# Spring Integration cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'expression' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:filter'

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am upgrading application to spring 5 and using spring-integration getting below two errors on configuration

configuration:

```
<int:filter id="xpathfilter" input-channel="eventSpringXpathChannel"
    output-channel="eventSpringOutChannel" discard-channel="eventSpringFailureChannel"
    expression="#xpath(payload, headers.get('xpathKey'), 'boolean')">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onFailureExpressionString" value="payload" />
            <property name="failureChannel" ref="eventSpringXpathErrorChannel" />
            <property name="trapException" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:filter>
```

Two ERRORS:
1) cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'expression' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:filter'

```
2) Invalid element name:
- request-handler-advice-chain

One of the following is expected:
- bean
- poller
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct. That attribute is definitely there and it was never changed:

```
<xsd:complexType name="expressionOrInnerEndpointDefinitionAwareNoAdviceChain">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="handlerEndpointType">
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="2">
                <xsd:element name="poller" type="basePollerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="expression" type="innerExpressionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:attribute name="expression" type="xsd:string">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        A SpEL expression to be evaluated against the input Message as its root object.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I assume the problem is more about your IDE not to be compliant with Spring XML configuration. Consider to use STS or IntelliJ IDEA.

Otherwise, please, share more how you got that error.

Comment: Thanks..I am using STS.. What about other error    Invalid element name:
- request-handler-advice-chain.  Is this tag present inside int:filter ?

Comment: It is. See `spring-integration.xsd` in the `spring-integration-core` jar. There is a `filter-type` `<xsd:complexType>` definition and it has that `request-handler-advice-chain` element in its content. You need to see how to enable your STS to scan classpath for XSDs, not asking the Internet. Your question is more like: how to make STS understanding Spring XSD from classpath? Rather than Spring Integration concern. If you would move away from XML to Java configuration, you wouldn't fight the IDE configuration for XML support.

Comment: Thanks. fixed related STS issues